# How to send an html page as email in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, html-email

I recently started programming my first node.js. I can't find any modules from node that is able to send html page as email. please help, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have been using this module: https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

Updated example(using express and nodemailer) that includes getting index.jade template from the file system and sending it as an email:

```
var _jade = require('jade');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var FROM_ADDRESS = 'foo@bar.com';
var TO_ADDRESS = 'test@test.com';

// create reusable transport method (opens pool of SMTP connections)
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "bar@foo.com",
        pass: "PASSWORD"
    }
});

var sendMail = function(toAddress, subject, content, next){
  var mailOptions = {
    from: "SENDERS NAME <" + FROM_ADDRESS + ">",
    to: toAddress,
    replyTo: fromAddress,
    subject: subject,
    html: content
  };

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, next);
}; 

exports.index = function(req, res){
  // res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

  // specify jade template to load
  var template = process.cwd() + '/views/index.jade';

  // get template from file system
  fs.readFile(template, 'utf8', function(err, file){
    if(err){
      //handle errors
      console.log('ERROR!');
      return res.send('ERROR!');
    }
    else {
      //compile jade template into function
      var compiledTmpl = _jade.compile(file, {filename: template});
      // set context to be used in template
      var context = {title: 'Express'};
      // get html back as a string with the context applied;
      var html = compiledTmpl(context);

      sendMail(TO_ADDRESS, 'test', html, function(err, response){
        if(err){
          console.log('ERROR!');
          return res.send('ERROR');
        }
        res.send("Email sent!");
      });
    }
  });
};
```

I'd probably move the mailer part to its own module but I included everything here so you can see it all together.

Comment: I have used it too but it is can not sent a complicated template

Comment: What do you mean by complicated template? As long as your template is compiled to a string I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: awesome, your example works so great. It is easy to understand. Again, thanks so much!

Comment: How can we set _src=_ for '<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">'. I think we will attach file _smiley.gif_ to email. Is that right?. Do you have example code?, thanks!

Comment: its fine but how to load my custom css and image in the users mail... they are not loading :((

Comment: I would do this for cross platform and reduced potential bugs around paths, because why not: 

`var template = path.join(process.cwd(), '/views/index.jade');`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `nodemailer` and `nodemailer-express-handlebars` modules do this:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var mailerhbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');

var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: Gmail,  // More at https://nodemailer.com/smtp/well-known/#supported-services
    auth: {
        user: [USERNAME@gmail.com], // Your email id
        pass: [PASSWORD] // Your password
    }
});

mailer.use('compile', mailerhbs({
    viewPath: 'templates/default/emails', //Path to email template folder
    extName: '.hbs' //extendtion of email template
}));
```

In router post you can use:

```
mailer.sendMail({
            from: 'Your name username@domain.com',
            to: user.local.email,
            subject: 'Reset your password',
            template: 'password_reset', //Name email file template
            context: { // pass variables to template
                hostUrl: req.headers.host,
                customeName: user.info.firstname + ' ' + user.info.lastname,
                resetUrl: req.headers.host + '/users/recover/' + token,
                resetCode: token
            }
        }, function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                res.send('Error send email, please contact administrator to best support.');
            }
            res.send('Email send successed to you email' + req.body.email + '.');
            done(err, 'done');
        });
```

In hbs template you can use variables:

```
{{var from context}}
```

hope blocks of code to help you.

Comment: its necessary to give extName only .hbs ? can i use .html ?

Comment: You can use the syntax of the `engine` template to display a variable in `.html`

Comment: i am using html view engine. can't access context variable  in html file. how can i do?

Comment: i passed like this context : {name : 'myname'}

Comment: how can i use name ? in html