# Send raw email file with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, email, bulk, nodemailer

I tried to send some email contained in a file with nodemailer for nodejs, to do that i first parsed the file with mailparser and then send the object returned with node mailer, the problem is that it seems that it doubles the headers, creating two from:, two to: etc...
I'm wondering if there is another way to make nodemailer read files from a directory and send them, or if you know some other way i could do that.

I have some files that gets accumulated in a directory and each day at 8am, they are all sent to a server. The time can change but thats not relevent i guess :). thanks for any help or tips you guys can give and the others for reading :P.

Here is the exemple of code i'm using as asked

```
var fs = require('fs');
var MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser;
var file = './113B797D-69F0-4127-A4CE-27923E7006CF.3.1';
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 port: 2529,
 host: '127.0.0.1'
});
var mailparser = new MailParser();
mailparser.on("error", function(err) {
   console.log('[Error] mailparser: '+err);
});

mailparser.on("end", function(mail_object) { 
  console.log(mail_object);
  transporter.sendMail(mail_object);
});
fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(mailparser);
```

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994023/sending-html-email-with-node-js

Comment: I saw this before but he creates his own header, or in my case the header is already there and with all the fields, which is why my mails get rejected when i send it with the mailparser because it duplicates all fields. In the worst case i might try to "hack" the mailparser but i was hoping not to get to that point :x

Comment: Could you post some code what you are doing?  It is kinda hard to understand your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport 
var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.email.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'test@email.com',
        pass: 'passHere'
    }
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    envelope: {
        from: 'test@email.com', // sender address
        to: 'email@test.com'    // list of receivers
    },
    raw: {
        path: '/path/to/file.eml'
    }
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

Comment: hey, how would you add attachments to the request?

Comment: Any attachments should be encapsulated in the .eml file