# Nodemailer works but how do I use it in my webpage .html form

Tags: html, node.js, nodemailer

Im using `nodemailer` (working well in console).

I pretend handler data from my html page and using into `nodemailer` and run from my browser (is a contact form).

"http://localhost/contact.html"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654051/how-to-send-an-html-page-as-email-in-nodejs

Comment: You can't and don't want to run nodemailer from in the browser. That would give everyone unfederated access to send emails through your domain. The users should submit a form back to your site, and your *server* can then do the proper checks and send an email.