# Node js + template replace content

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working to generate offer letter for employees. So I have some default template index.html:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>Offer Letter</h1>
</div>

<div id="name">
 Hello [[Name]],

Welcome to our organization,'

Details:

[[Date]]    : Offer Letter Date
[[Name]]    : Employee Name
[[Designation]] : Designation
[[Address]] : Communication Address
[[CTC]]  : Cost to the Company

</div>

<div id="footer">
Copyright
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am generate multiple offers at a time more than 300.

So I have json data like this:

```
var obj = [
 { "name" : "Abc",
  "Date" : "12-12-2014",
  "Designation" : "Admin",
  "Address" : "XXXX",
  "CTC" : 3333},
{ "name" : "wefrwe",
  "Date" : "12-12-2014",
  "Designation" : "Admin",
  "Address" : "XXXX",
  "CTC" : 55},
{ "name" : "dssd",
  "Date" : "12-12-2015",
  "Designation" : "Admin",
  "Address" : "XXXX",
  "CTC" : 333},
{ "name" : "gfsc",
  "Date" : "12-1-2014",
  "Designation" : "Admin",
  "Address" : "XXXX",
  "CTC" : 22},
{ "name" : "dssdds",
  "Date" : "1-12-2014",
  "Designation" : "Admin",
  "Address" : "XXXX",
  "CTC" : 4334}
];
```

How do I replace values (eg. [[Name]] to Abc ) .

Have any node packages ?

I tried the following code but don't know this is best way and useful.

```
for(i in obj) {


var textbody = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> <div id="header"> <h1>Offer Letter</h1> </div> <div id="name"> Hello [[name]], Welcome to our organization,' Details: [[Date]] : Offer Letter Date [[Name]]    : Employee Name [[Designation]] : Designation [[Address]]   : Communication Address [[CTC]]  : Cost to the Company </div> <div id="footer"> Copyright </div> </body> </html>';


textbody = textbody.replace(/{[^{{}}]+}/g, function(key){
    return obj[key.replace(/[{{}}]+/g, "")] || "";
});

}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a template engine.

Comment: The main concept is.  We have html content(index.html) in tables.  So I need to render data form database table and read then replace the content then need to create html file and pdf file.

Comment: Well, the template engine will help generate your HTML dynamically using the data from your database. You can use a tool like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to create a PDF from a webpage (see: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html).

Answer (score 3):

[mustache.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache) is a zero-dependency implementation of the mustache template system in JavaScript.

[Mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache) is a logic-less template syntax. It can be used for HTML, config files, source code - anything. It works by expanding tags in a template using values provided in a hash or object.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for sending email using node, nodemailer & jade

[How to send an html page as email in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654051/how-to-send-an-html-page-as-email-in-nodejs)

Your jade template should be similar(or better than) to:

```
doctype html
html
    head
    body
        p
            | Hello #{newemp.name},
            br
            br
            | Welcome to our organization.
            br
            br
            | Details:
            br
            | #{newemp.Date}  : Offer Letter Date
            br
            | #{newemp.name}  : Employee Name
            br
            | #{newemp.Designation}  : Designation
            br
            | #{newemp.Address}  : Communication Address
            br
            | #{newemp.CTC}  : Cost to the Company
```

and

in the referred link, you need to pass the context as below:

```
var context = { 
                 "name" : "Abc",
                 "Date" : "12-12-2014",
                 "Designation" : "Admin",
                 "Address" : "XXXX",
                 "CTC" : 3333
              };
```

I did harcode the context variable with one employee object for simplicity, you need to dynamically pass each employee object for each email.

Comment: jade, pug, similar things.