# React-Native send html formatted email

Tags: javascript, android, html, email, react-native

I can't figure out how to send an HTML formatted Email from React-Native. I have tried with both React-Native-Communications and React-Native-Mail but both cause the html tags to appear as text in the email body. I even set the isHTML flag to true in RN-mail and it did not help on Android (haven't tested iOS though). How can I do this?

Comment: <a href="mailto:danny@danny4help.com">Mail</a>
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

Comment: As far as Google and I know mailto doesn't support hmtl formatted body text

Comment: Not sure if this is language-specific, but it can be done on the server-side using php's mail function as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used React-Native-Communications and React-Native-Mail (ones that you mentioned), but since React Native is also a node based framework, you can try using  https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer library. It sure sends html content in mails. and to help you get started, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654249/6774212) answer with example usage of this module. Even you can seperate it in a component of your own later on to maintain modularity. I hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that I want to send the mail directly with the app but rather that I want to invoke the creation of a new mail in the default mail app so that the user can send it from his own address

Comment: According to RFC 2368 document that I came across, it seems its not possible to embed HTML content in mailto URL scheme. Here 's the [link](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2368)  for more info on this