# nodemailer - passed vars with html coding

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I´ve a question regarding nodemailer.

I´m attaching a html file to the html:

```
...
html: file.html
...
```

but I´m also passing some html code within the vars, e.g. {{welcomeText}} (within the html file)

But as a result I receive in the email:

> Hi < b >Bold< / b> men, ......

How can I define the passed vars to be transalted also to html?

here is my function:

template = *path to html file*
templateData is an object. Those data I get with {{varName}} within the html file.

```
function sendMail(recipients, subject, template, templateData){
    var mailConf = {
        direct: true,
        host: 'hostname'
    };

    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(mailConf);

    if (!templateData){
        console.warn('No template data');
        return;
    }

    templateData.from = 'noreply@123.com';
    templateData.subject = subject;
    templateData.html = template;

    var mail = transport.templateSender(templateData);

    mail({to: recipients}, convertToObject(templateData), function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.warn(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', data.messageId);
    });
}
```

thanks a lot for your help,
Adrian

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21654249/7707749 have you seen this answer how to send a mail with a html file? I can't see your code, but I know this one works.

Comment: thanks, but this is already working. I am able to send out a html email, but the variable I pass to it, like {{welcomeText}} which includes also html coding, is not rendered as html.

Comment: I assume you also use a template then? because I can't see your code it's just a guessing game.

Comment: ok - I have updated my post. hope this is more clear. thanks anyways