# Is there a way to send an email in a React Native app as a form?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a form (similar to Google forms) where the user has text input they must enter. If they press "submit" (like a google form), I want it to send the entire form to an email address. I have an image of how it looks below.
[image]

I followed this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgWGllOjkbs&ab_channel=RemyFamily), but I am not sure how to write the return method in React Native because the video is written in React. I also tried to follow this Node.js [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654051/how-to-send-an-html-page-as-email-in-nodejs/21654249#21654249) but it doesn't work because of the required engines like jade. Please let me know if you can help. I think the video is my best bet because it matches what I'm trying to do, but when I tried to write it in React Native it kept telling me that my input didn't fit the HTML form required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

#1 send the email trough a backend (more complex as you need an email server or mail api like Mailgun)

#2 open the installed email client and prefill the fields (easy because of built-in functions):

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description') }
      title="support@example.com" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response. I am receiving this error with the onPress method:  Error: Unable to open URL mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description

Comment: Nevermind, it just didn't work when using an iOS simulator. When I tried it on my device, it is referring me to open the Gmail app or the Mail app. I am purposefully trying to do this on the same screen in the app and not use outside apps, and have the user fill out the form on that screen shown in the image above, and similarly to Google Forms, once they press submit, it will send the entire form to an email. Is this possible?

Comment: Use Mailgun which will provide an API for sending emails.